# Copy stored jQuery object while maintaining delegated events

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dynamic table where users can add and delete rows. When the user clicks a button to add a row, I want to insert into the DOM a stored jQuery object which is a copy of the initial table row `.baseRow`. Within this row, I also want to have a delegated click event that stays alive for future added rows.

However, two issues are presenting themselves with my current implementation (tested in Chrome/IE). The first is that the click handler breaks after the first event is fired. I am able to solve this by chaining `.html()` after `.clone()`, but when I do that the clone is inexplicably stripped of the parent `tr` element and is reduced to just the children elements.

See [this js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YxB9J/3/) for an example of the issue, or below for a sample of the code:

**JS**

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    var $baseRow = $('.baseRow').clone(true,true); 
    $('table').delegate('.addRow','click',function(){
        $('tbody').append($baseRow);
    });
});​
```

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Add Row</th>
            <th>Header 1</th>
            <th>Header 2</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="baseRow">
            <td class="addRow">+</td>
            <td>Body 1</td>
            <td>Body 2</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You clone once, and append that cloned element over and over. Since there is only one clone, you won't ever have more than two elements (original + clone). Instead, clone when clicked, so that the amount of clones equals the amount of clicks: http://jsfiddle.net/YxB9J/5/.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $baseRow = $('.baseRow'); 
    $('table').delegate('.addRow','click',function(){
        $('tbody').append($baseRow.clone(true, true));
    });
});
```

Comment: That is very interesting! I was under the impression that one clone could be used for multiple copies, and therefore by cloning once I was simply being more efficient.

Comment: @Moses: Basically, what you call a "copy" is exactly what a "clone" is. `.clone()` just gives you one single new element like the original - the clone doesn't have "special" features or something.

Comment: Right, I was just expecting it to behave similarly to a copy/paste in traditional OSes, where a copy persists for multiple pastes. That doesn't appear to be the case, however.

Comment: One issue I've noticed is that this doesn't make a copy at DOMReady, but instead on click event. This means it has the unintended consequence of copying values that the user enters into the new rows. Any idea on how to avoid that?

Comment: @Mosts: Yes, it does, because it clones the (visible) first row. You could as well clone once at document ready, so that the element you're cloning on click is an (invisible) clone itself. The user is therefore not able to change the values of that element, so you will be cloning a clean element each time.

Comment: @Moses: For what it's worth, here's a little copy/paste plugin that mimics the OS concept: http://jsfiddle.net/YxB9J/7/.